# UIActionSheet - "init" changes button style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet, init

Why does the button style on a UIActionSheet for the "cancel" button change when I add "Init" after allocating and initializing it once?

If I use this code it shows up properly:

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo/Camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Capture - Camera", @"Upload - Photo Library", nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
```

[image]

If I use this code (with `...init]` added) it shows up im-properly and the "cancel" button style is changed:

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo/Camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Capture - Camera", @"Upload - Photo Library", nil] init];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:self.view];
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you `init`ing twice?

Comment: I'm not in my real project, I'm just curious why when you do it changes the button style.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a question of curiosity (there is NO valid reason for the double "init").

The second `init` most likely resets many of the ivars setup in the first `initWithTitle...`. Most obviously the `cancelButtonIndex` is being reset so the Cancel button appears as a regular button.

Comment: (Yes it's out of curiosity) Ahh! This makes since! But I wonder, if it's resetting the variables, why doesn't it also reset the "titles" to "(nil)" or something?

Comment: Without the source code there is no way to know exactly what happens. It seems clear that `init` doesn't assign anything to the array of buttons or the title. The array may get lazily set the first time `addButtonWithTitle` is called.